# Convert RDD[(Int,Int)] to PairRDD in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What is the problem with this example ?

```
val f = sc.parallelize(Array((1,1),(1,2)))
val p = new org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions[Int,Int](f)

Name: Compile Error
Message:  error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)]
       val p = new org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions[Int,Int](f)
                                                                  ^
```

Comment: What version of spark and scala are you using?

Comment: SPARK sc.version ->  2.4.0-SNAPSHOT and Scala 
 util.Properties.versionString -> version 2.11.8

Comment: I downgraded SPARK to 2.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine on Spark 2.2.0.

This is the transcript of the console commands in Spark version 2.2.0:

```
scala> val f = sc.parallelize(Array((1,1),(1,2)))
f: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val p = new org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions[Int,Int](f)
p: org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions[Int,Int] = org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@6e1d939e

scala> p
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions[Int,Int] = org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@6e1d939e

scala> f
res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24
```

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131)

This seems to be a bug in an older version to me.

Comment: I downgraded SPARK to 2.3. Thanks.